# Is there a way to get a value if it is null without doing an "if" check?

Tags: c#

My code currently looks like this:

```
if (App.cardSetWithWordCount == null)
                App.cardSetWithWordCount = App.DB.GetCardSetWithWordCount(Settings.cc.Text());
```

I realize this is already just almost a one line check but wondering with the latest release of C# is there now a way to code this construct that's even cleaner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no cleaner way, only more verbose and less readable ways, i think you should be happy with what you have.

```
if (App.cardSetWithWordCount == null)
   App.cardSetWithWordCount = App.DB.GetCardSetWithWordCount(Settings.cc.Text());
```

Though you could do this

```
App.cardSetWithWordCount = App.cardSetWithWordCount ?? App.DB.GetCardSetWithWordCount(Settings.cc.Text());
```

---

**Additional Resources**

[?? Operator (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator)

> The ?? operator is called the null-coalescing operator. It returns the
>   left-hand operand if the operand is not null; otherwise it returns the
>   right hand operand.

Answer (score 1):

Some minor modification below:

```
if (App?.cardSetWithWordCount != null && App.cardSetWithWordCount > 0)
// do something
else
App.cardSetWithWordCount = App.DB.GetCardSetWithWordCount(Settings.cc.Text());
```

Just added an else for a more deterministic approach. Also, if your Count is a list, then you can use `.Any()` as well.

C# 6.0 comes with [Monadic null checking](https://www.nhaustralia.com.au/blog/Automatic-null-checking-in-C-sharp-6-0/).

As per the above link:

**Before:**

```
if    (Title != null 
&& this.Title.Length > 0 )
{
    // safe to use
}
```

**After:**

```
if    (this.Title?.Length > 0 ) 
{ ... }
```